# ggplot geom_point Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text issue?

Tags: r, text, ggplot2

I am generating an SVG facet chart. I want a tooltip to appear on hover over the points. I am using a `text` aesthetic in ggplot/geom_point to craft the tooltip text.

A warning is produced... `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text`. In spite of the warning, it does in fact produce a tooltip as I have defined it below in the `sprintf` of `geom_point`. However, once the number of facets in the chart exceed 21, the tooltip only appears for a subset of the points. It just seems unreliable. However, removing the `text` aesthetic always results in a default tooltip for **all** points across **any** number of facets. When including the `text` aesthetic the tooltip generated is a combination of default text and the bespoke text that I have defined and looks like this...[screenshot of tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNpde.png)... not ideal but at least it contains the information I want to show, in particular the Rate/'000 as an actual value rather than as a log value.

Should I avoid this functionality or is there a better, more reliable, way to achieve this effect?

```
    p <- ggplot(data=df.data_chart_category
               ,aes(x=TourDate, y=rate_per_thousand_lifts, group=key, colour=factor(key))
               ,environment = environment()
        ) +
        geom_point(aes(size = size, text = sprintf("Rate/'000: %s<br>Misses: %s<br>Hits: %s<br>Total Lifts: %s", rate_per_thousand_lifts, misses, hits, total_tour_count)), alpha=0.4) +
        scale_size(name = "Bin count", breaks = c(10, 50, 100, 500, 800, 1000), range = c(1,12)) +
        scale_color_manual("", values = c("Lifter1" = "red", "Lifter2" = "green", "Lifter3" = "lightblue", "Lifter4" = "purple", "NoLifter" = "cyan", "GPS" = "darkgrey")) +
        guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=10))) +
        facet_wrap(as.formula(paste("~", facet_wrap_column_name)), ncol=number_of_facet_columns) +
        labs(x = x_axis_label, y = snr_y_axis_label, title = snr_chart_title, subtitle = snr_chart_subtitle, caption = snr_chart_caption, color="Lifter") +
        theme_few() +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=-0.01)) + 
        theme(axis.title = element_text(size = axis_font_size)) + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(color = '#666666', 
                                  face = 'bold',
                                  size = title_font_size,
                                  hjust = 0)) + 
        scale_y_log10()

    pp <- ggplotly(p)
    htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget=pp, file="index.html", selfcontained=FALSE)
```

Comment: I've had a look at the plot object and it is clear that the correct text is assigned to the plot object elements. Iterating through the object is not going to help here and in any case that appears to me to be a little tricky given the presence of facets. I have put a fully working example at [https://github.com/liamcaffrey/svg_tooltip.git](https://github.com/liamcaffrey/svg_tooltip.git) with dput data. I have included example png and html/svg files. The tooltips appear to always work on the zero values and sometimes on the non-zero values

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the solutions here are correct as this is obviously a bug as the text attribute is perfectly valid in `geom_point` or `geom_vline` (which I was using) from the point of view of ggplotly so my solution to this would be:

```
gg <- gg + suppressWarnings(geom_point(aes(size = size, text = sprintf("Rate/'000: %s<br>Misses: %s<br>Hits: %s<br>Total Lifts: %s", rate_per_thousand_lifts, misses, hits, total_tour_count)), alpha=0.4))
```

Answer (score 2):

I got my example working somewhat as I expected. I wasn't really understanding how to set up bespoke tooltips. I've posted a working example [here](https://github.com/liamcaffrey/svg_tooltip/blob/master/SVG_tooltip_working.R). Data for the example can still be found at [TooltipNotWorkingData.txt](https://github.com/liamcaffrey/svg_tooltip)

The main issue related to my tooltip parameter placement.

```
    p <- ggplot(data=df.data_chart_category
               ,aes(x=calendar_day, y=rate_per_thousand, group=key, colour=factor(key), text = tooltip, onclick = clickjs)
               ,environment = environment()
        )
```

It should be part of ggplot/aes and not geom_point/aes. Referencing tooltip in the ggplotly call `pp <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = "tooltip")` is necessary to override the default tooltip.

I'm still having problems with tooltip display on certain size charts and I've opened a new question for that on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144245/tooltip-not-working-on-chart-depending-on-chart-size).

Answer (score 1):

Problems with `plotly`'s tooltip are usually fixed building the plot object and the fiddling with `text` inside it:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df.data_chart_category)){
    pp$x$data[[i]]$text <- c(pp$x$data[[i]]$text, "") 
}
```

It's kinda hard to check if it works in this case as we don't have the original dataframe or a reproducible example.

Comment: Ok. That looks neat. Thank you. I will give it a try. I'm reading this on my phone so I can't play with it right now either! It looks like you are accessing the `text` of the `data` of the `x` for each row. I can't see it but is there not a `y` part as well?  The tooltip is for the combination of `x` and `y`. Sorry about no code but a pointer in the right direction is appreciated. I'll have a poke around in the innards of `pp` tomorrow.

Comment: `for (i in 1:length(pp$x$data)){
    pp$x$data[[i]]$text <- c(_vector_of_length_count_of_x_)
}` where _vector_of_length_count_of_x_ is built from contents of `df.data_chart_category`. I've a bit more investigation to do here but I think I know what to do. Tnx

Comment: I've had a look at the plot object and it is clear that the correct text is assigned to the plot object elements. Iterating through the object is not going to help here and in any case that appears to me to be a little tricky given the presence of facets. I have put a fully working example at [link](https://github.com/liamcaffrey/svg_tooltip.git) with dput data. I have included example png and html/svg files. The tooltips appear to always work on the zero values and sometimes on the non-zero values.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is old but I found a solution that worked for me.

I kept running into this issue when trying to update the `tooltips = "text"` parameter in `ggplotly()` and becoming frustrated when for some reason it would not update using the mapping from ggplot.

One weird thing I found is that for some reason when `stat = "sum"` it won't update the text in the tooltip and returns the error `Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text` when generating the plot. However, both `stat = "count"` and `stat = "identity"` work just fine.