# Tooltips for high points on low-height charts not displaying

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, plotly

I have a problem with tooltips not showing depending on the size of the chart/browser window. This originally looked to me like a problem with facet charts but the behaviour is also evident on regular/single charts. I've done a lot of searching for this and not found anything so far. There is a similar post over on plotly forums with no answers as of yet.

Here is an MRE for a single chart ([HT](https://github.com/bhive01))...

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)

randomName <- function(n) {
    random.string <- rep(NA, n)
    randomizeString <- function(x) {
        a <-sample(letters, 1, replace = TRUE)
        return(a)
    }
    return(paste(c(sapply(random.string, randomizeString, simplify = TRUE)), collapse = ""))
}

xvar = replicate(10, randomName(15))

df1 <- data.frame(x = xvar, y = xvar, z = runif(10) )

df1$tooltip <- sprintf("x: %s<br>y: %s<br>z: %s<br>2x: %s<br>2y: %s<br>2z: %s<br>3x: %s<br>3y: %s<br>3z: %s"
                                        ,df1$x, df1$y, df1$z, df1$x, df1$y, df1$z, df1$x, df1$y, df1$z)

g = ggplot(df1, aes(x,y,fill=z, text = tooltip)) +
        geom_tile()

ggplotly(g, tooltip = "tooltip")
```

If you resize the browser window to a small enough height you will notice that the tooltip will not be displayed when hovering over the tiles near the top of the chart. The problem appears to be that the tooltip is too tall to display whereby the hover position would place the top of the tooltip box outside the top of the chart. This kind of makes sense even if problematic. However, this MRE example is a bit contrived and unrealistic.

This behaviour becomes a real issue on a facet chart with a large number of facets requiring tooltips. Here is an MRE for a facet chart. Even with a maximised browser window the same tooltip issue is evident.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)

randomName <- function(n) {
    random.string <- rep(NA, n)
    randomizeString <- function(x) {
        a <-sample(letters, 1, replace = TRUE)
        return(a)
    }
    return(paste(c(sapply(random.string, randomizeString, simplify = TRUE)), collapse = ""))
}

xvar = replicate(10, randomName(15))
facet_var = replicate(12, randomName(2))

df1 <- data.frame(x = xvar, y = xvar, z = runif(10) )
df1 <- merge(x = facet_var, y = df1, by = NULL)

#df1$tooltip <- sprintf("x: %s<br>y: %s<br>z: %s<br>x+x: %s<br>y+y: %s<br>z+z: %s"
df1$tooltip <- sprintf("facet: %s<br>x: %s<br>y: %s<br>z: %s<br>2x: %s<br>2y: %s<br>2z: %s<br>3x: %s<br>3y: %s<br>3z: %s"
                                        ,df1$x.x, df1$x.y, df1$y, df1$z, df1$x.y, df1$y, df1$z, df1$x.y, df1$y, df1$z)

g = ggplot(df1, aes(x.y,y,fill=z, text = tooltip)) +
        geom_tile() +
        facet_wrap(~x.x, ncol=2)

ggplotly(g, tooltip = "tooltip")
```

This issue exists both for default and bespoke tooltips - tested in Chrome(v56) and Edge(v38).

I had an [earlier question posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974231/ggplot-geom-point-ignoring-unknown-aesthetics-text-issue/42977851#42977851) on SO regarding this issue but my analysis was off the mark, and my example not an MRE, and I have closed/answered that question since.

I could reduce the number of lines in the tooltip to obviate the problem but I'd prefer not to have to do that. Is this a known feature or is there a workaround for this behaviour?

Comment: In your 2nd example: Does the tooltip only work for the first plot or is that just my specific environment?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters The tooltip will only show for those points where the geometry (available real estate) of the chart would allow a tooltip to be placed there. The tooltip won't "float" out over the edge of a chart. In the second (facet) example that you ran in your environment, you can see that the facet charts on the 2nd line of the plot are very shallow compared to the first line and there is just not enough space to show the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Adding hovermode "closest" to layout fixed it.

js:

```
layout:{...,hovermode:"closest"}
```

R (based on Maximillian Peters' answer, but untested):

```
gp <- ggplotly(g, tooltip = "tooltip")
gp[['x']][['layout']][['hovermode']]='closest'
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility/workaround would be to set `hovermode` to `'y'`, i.e. change the last line of your example to:

```
gp <- ggplotly(g, tooltip = "tooltip")
gp[['x']][['layout']][['hovermode']]='y'
```

Reduced window size in RStudio for your first example
[image]

Part of the fullscreen for your second example.
[image]

Comment: The same problem remains using hovermode. In fact it highlights the behaviour even more as evident in these examples. ![hovermode low y point](https://github.com/liamcaffrey/svg_tooltip/blob/master/Hovermode_low_point.png) and ![hovermode high y point](https://github.com/liamcaffrey/svg_tooltip/blob/master/Hovermode_high_point.png).

Comment: At least it shows something :/ Seems like something one should request from the Plotly makers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can see of working around this behaviour is to ensure that the tootip is no more that 1 or two lines deep which is, I suppose, what the intention of a tooltip is in the first place! That is what I am going to go with.

I was hoping to elaborate on the "tooltip" to have a nicely formatted tooltip containing a td/table. Maybe there is an alternative approach to achieving this effect?